# Why did this AC with a shared condenser stop working?

Tags: air-conditioning

We've got 3 indoor air-con units that are connected to 1 outdoor condenser unit. Only my unit blows air in room temperature (not cold), the rest of the indoor units blow cold air. My indoor unit blows a lot of air and is not blocked. I tried touching the coils but it's not cold.

It's been working before and it just suddenly stopped cooling the air it blows.

There are two LED lights turned on in front of my indoor unit which means cooling mechanism is on (AC is in the right mode). When it reaches its desired temperature (coldness) it stops cooling and only 1 LED light is turned on. But in my case, two LED lights are always turned on when it stopped cooling the air.

What could be the cause of problem?

EDIT:

Indoor unit: Mitsubishi MS-A10VD
Outdoor unit: Mitsubishi MUX-3D23VD

Here's the condenser unit showing the 
[image: Condenser Unit]

Actualy 2 units are not working. As you can see in the pipes, 2 pipes to the working unit were moist and the rest were dry. I tried an experiment just to make sure that the two non-working units are eletrically connected to the condenser. I turned off all AC units and the condenser's fan stopped. I turned on one of the two non working units while the working unit is turned off, the condenser turned on. Which means the two non AC units are electrically connected to the condenser.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Comment: What is the make and model of the indoor and outdoor units?  Have you consulted the user manual?  Have you contacted customer support?

Answer (score -1):

Disconnect C2 and measure the capacitance for 25uF. If the reading is out, replace the capacitor.